# Custom Error Message after Datatables ajax exception

Tags: ajax, exception, datatables

I am displaying a table of data using datatables 1.10.12.  The user can specify input parameters that cause an error on the server.  An appropriate error message should be displayed to the user so they can modify their setup, however the only error options seem to be:

1. SHow the following generic error in an alert: "DataTables warning: table id=trackingTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7"
2. Show the generic error in the browser console
3. Modify the server to return no rows, that is fail silently.

Does anyone know how to show a custom error after a datatables ajax request fails?

The following code sample is taken from the datatables [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html).  Datatables handles the ajax call and handles success and error.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
    } );
} );
```

A 4th option I could add to the list would be to modify the datatables source code to handle the an error response myself. Which I'm not that keen on.

This question was asked in 2015 however it did not get an answer. See:
[display server side exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940524/display-server-side-exception-message-on-datatables-net)

Comment: many ways to do that.. you can apply try catch in javascript function while sending an ajax request as well as you can show error message at ajax `error` function if any error occurred.

Comment: Thanks mmushtaq.  How do I add the try catch to the datatables ajax request?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://datatables.net/reference/event/error

Comment: This is good.  Thanks @Adam.  However I can't see how to get access to the error message or status that was returned by the ajax call.

Answer (score 35):

If you pass an object to the *ajax* property you can override the jQuery.ajax() error method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: '../ajax/data/arrays.txt',
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Do something here
            }
        }
    });
});
```

https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#object

This will stop the standard error message in the `alert` box.

Please note, it is not recommended to override the *success* method of jQuery.ajax() as it is used by DataTables.

Comment: not really, this works only if you call ajax standalone, with datatable, error is useless, tried it and it doesn't catch a thing. seems like you cannot override the error function

Answer (score 11):

You can implement your own custom error message globally like the example below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = () => alert('Error while loading the table data. Please refresh');
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Answering just in case someone is still looking for a solution.

In my case, I did the following

1. At server side set `DataTablesOutput` `object.setError("ErrorMsg")`
2. In my js method `$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';` to avoid the error `popup`.
3. Created an error `div` in my page to display the custom error message
4. Added the below to my js method to handle error

   ```
   $('#myDataTable')
           .on('error.dt',
               function(e, settings, techNote, message) {//Logic to set the div innertext 
                }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
     try {
     $.ajax({
       -------
       -------
    success: function (data){
         //ShowDataTable is a js Function which takes ajax response data and display it.
           ShowDataTable(data);
    },
      //this error will catch server-side error if request fails
      error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert(errorThrown);
         ShowDataTable(null);
       } 
      })

     }
    //this catch block will catch javascript exceptions,
    catch (Error) {
                if (typeof console != "undefined") {
                    console.log(Error);
                    ShowDataTable(null);                    
                    alert(Error);
                 }
              }
```

***EDIT***

If you are willing to accept the error (for example if you cannot alter the backend system to fix the error), but don't want your end users to see the alert() message, you can change DataTables' error reporting mechanism to throw a Javascript error to the browser's console, rather than alerting it. This can be done using:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
```

Comment: I don't think this is a solution.   DataTables [link](https://datatables.net/) handles the ajax call itself.  I've updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: On the plus side I spent a fair bit of time today adding code to prevent the user setting up an invalid request in the first place.  However it seems  desirable to have the capacity to display meaningful error messages resulting from server side faults on occaision so I assume Datatables must be able to do this.

Comment: The `Error` that you have mentioned is due failure of `ajax request`. . Simply add `try catch` in `Document.Ready()` to catch `JS exceptions`. The other solution is provided in `DataTable Error link` .. See my edit